# GitHub Action In-line if

Tags: github-actions

So I have the following workflow and its working perfectly. I now want to enhance it and when I am doing a PR to master, I want to set `NETLIFY_DEPLOY_TO_PROD: false` instead of it being true? Do I have to duplicate this all in a new workflow, or could do some inline if check of `github.event_name === push ? true : false`

```
name: 'Netlify Deploy'

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: jsmrcaga/action-netlify-deploy@master
        with:
          NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN }} 
          NETLIFY_SITE_ID: ${{ secrets.SITE_ID }} 
          NETLIFY_DEPLOY_MESSAGE: "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
          NETLIFY_DEPLOY_TO_PROD: true
```

Comment: Are you ever going to push to master directly, or only ever merge PRs into it? If it's the latter, you can switch the trigger to run the workflow only when a PR into master is closed, and then you can check in an `if` clause if it was merged or closed.

Comment: @BenjaminW. it is possible that I would do direct, but it will mostly be PR

Comment: So all pushes to master should trigger the workflow as you have it, and PRs into master should also run it, but with the variable set differently, right?

Comment: @BenjaminW. When I PR to master I want this to run, but instead of passing true for deploy to prod I want false. Then when I close the PR and merge it, This sill run again and deploy it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set an environment variable to indicate if deploy to prod should happen, and change it depending on the event name:

```yaml
name: Netlify Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  DEPLOY: false

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deploy on pushes
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: echo 'DEPLOY=true' >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

      - uses: jsmrcaga/action-netlify-deploy@master
        with:
          NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN }}
          NETLIFY_SITE_ID: ${{ secrets.SITE_ID }}
          NETLIFY_DEPLOY_MESSAGE: ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
          NETLIFY_DEPLOY_TO_PROD: ${{ env.DEPLOY }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use github action expressions for this as it's quicker and you don't need any other unnecessary steps. I would only use steps to run scripts when they are more complex in nature

**Reference:** https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions

**Example 1:** Trigger on push

```
    - uses: jsmrcaga/action-netlify-deploy@master
      with:
        NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN }} 
        NETLIFY_SITE_ID: ${{ secrets.SITE_ID }} 
        NETLIFY_DEPLOY_MESSAGE: "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
        NETLIFY_DEPLOY_TO_PROD: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}
```

**Example 2 & Solution:** Trigger on push and branch is master

NOTE: You only need to check for branch master if you are planning to let this workflow run on other branches. Otherwise you can just use example 1 above that sets variable to true if event name is push only.

```
    - uses: jsmrcaga/action-netlify-deploy@master
      with:
        NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN }} 
        NETLIFY_SITE_ID: ${{ secrets.SITE_ID }} 
        NETLIFY_DEPLOY_MESSAGE: "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
        NETLIFY_DEPLOY_TO_PROD: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && contains(github.ref, 'master') }}
```

Comment: This is indeed more compact!